# foreach count only one result in form

Tags: laravel

I have this foreach

```
foreach ($categoryArr as $key => $value) {  
    
    foreach ($biciCorretta as $chiave => $valore) {
        
        $biciSingola = $valore;
        $contatoreqty =1;
        if ($biciSingola->category_id = $key && $contatoreqty <= $value) {
            
            if (!in_array($biciSingola,$biciSelezionata, true)) {
                array_push($biciSelezionata, $biciSingola);
            }
            $contatoreqty ++;
        } 
        
    }
    echo "$contatoreqty <br>";
}
```

this is dd $categoryAarr:

```
array:1 [▼
  1 => "1"
]
```

to be precise

```
array:1 [▼
  1(category id) => "1"(quantity request)
]
```

this is the dd of $biciCorretta (are the bikes I have in that category):

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => App\Models\Bike {#1461 ▶}
  1 => App\Models\Bike {#1459 ▶}
]
```

if the category of the single bike is correct and the quantity ($ value) is less than or equal to the counter
push the bike into the array.

I expect there is only one bike in the $biciSelezionata array as the quantity required is only one
instead the result is the following:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => App\Models\Bike {#1461 ▶}
  1 => App\Models\Bike {#1459 ▶}
]
```

Comment: I can't quite understand the problem, but already, you should separate your code and not overload everything in the same method

Comment: I changed the question
now the problem should be clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a problem on your condition
`if ($biciSingola->category_id = $key && $contatoreqty <= $value) {`

The condition here must be `==`

Write `if ($biciSingola->category_id == $key && $contatoreqty <= $value) {` instead

And its important where you initiate your $contatoreqty variable.
it will always be 1 if condition fails

Comment: unfortunately I have already tried this solution but the result does not change

Comment: I have update my answer. The is a problem with the $contatoreqty initialization

Comment: if I understand correctly you are advising me to remove the counter increment,
unfortunately also in this case the result has not changed

Comment: Not to remove, to change position, and put it before the foreach.

Comment: It would have been interesting to really understand the purpose of this algorithm, what should be done in the end?
Logic can help me to help you.